# Query to both group by a name in one column and show total for each grouped element

Tags: sql, mariadb, pivot

I have a table that looks something like this generic example.

```
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  id   |    name      |   amount   | payment_type  |   year    |  period  |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  1    |     Bob      |     20     |     BACS      |   2019    |     5    |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  2    |     Jim      |     40     |     BACS      |   2019    |     5    |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  3    |     Bob      |     60     |     BACS      |   2019    |     5    |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  4    |     Jim      |     20     |     Voucher   |   2019    |     5    |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  5    |     Bob      |     40     |     BACS      |   2019    |     5    |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  6    |     Bob      |     20     |     Cheque    |   2019    |     5    |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  7    |     Jim      |     20     |     BACS      |   2019    |     5    |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  8    |     Bob      |     20     |     BACS      |   2019    |     5    |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  9    |     Bob      |     20     |     BACS      |   2019    |     5    |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  10   |     Dan      |     20     |     BACS      |   2019    |     5    |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  11   |     Dan      |     20     |     Voucher   |   2019    |     5    |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
etc...
```

I would like to total up results of this table (Many more rows) and have a count of the total number of rows for each user, the total of the amount column for each user, and a total of each payment type for each user, narrowed down by year and period each time I run this query. (The year and period are user-select-able on a form.) So that I end up with a result set that looks something like this:

```
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  name |    Total     |   BACS     |    Cheque     |   Voucher |   Cost   |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  Bob  |      6       |     5      |       1       |     0     |    180   |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  Jim  |      3       |     2      |       0       |     1     |    80    |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
|  Dan  |      2       |     1      |       0       |     1     |    40    |
+-------+--------------+------------+---------------+-----------+----------+
```

So I need a pivoting query of some kind using a sum case something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR = '$safefy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 'BACs' OR payment_type = 'BACS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BACS,
    SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 'Cheque' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cheque,
    SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 'Voucher' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Voucher,
    <Not sure what goes here.> AS Cost,
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    YEAR = '2019' AND period = '5'
GROUP BY
    name "
```

But I'm not sure how to total up the cost from the tables amount column for each user. I'm probably not using the correct terms in my search for answers because I don't know what it's called?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want `sum(amount)`:

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR = '$safefy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 'BACs' OR payment_type = 'BACS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BACS,
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 'Cheque' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cheque,
       SUM(CASE WHEN payment_type = 'Voucher' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Voucher,
       SUM(amount) AS Cost
FROM table_name
WHERE YEAR = '2019' AND period = '5'
GROUP BY name;
```

You can simplify the first part because the `CASE` is not needed:

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(YEAR = '$safefy') AS total,
       SUM(payment_type IN ('BACs', 'BACS') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BACS,
       SUM(payment_type = 'Cheque') AS Cheque,
       SUM(payment_type = 'Voucher') AS Voucher,
       SUM(amount) AS Cost
FROM table_name
WHERE YEAR = '2019' AND period = '5'
GROUP BY name
```